# Динамическое добавление полей, для калькулятора

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать данный функционал как на скрине.

В каком то контейнере c возможностью scroll есть к примеру editText и под ним textView.
В edtiText вводится выражение в textView высчитывается ответ.

Но при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" создается новые editText и textView под уже существующими.

На данный момент есть такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут только 1 editText and 1 textView

Но никак не могу реализовать то что описал выше (что то по типу истории просчетов)

Comment: "историю просчетов" записываете в какое либо хранилище данных и потом выводите через ListView